# How to change the appearance of the googleplus-share button on the Gigya share bar?

Tags: google-plus, gigya

I'm trying to change the appearance of the googleplus-share button on the Gigya share bar. I'm able to change the appearance of the other buttons (Facebook, Twitter, etc, but the Google-plus button ignores the iconImgUp parameter specified by Gigya and reverts to the default appearance.

I'm using the follow parameter setup:

```
gigya.socialize.showShareBarUI({
    containerID : 'share-bar',
    shareButtons : [{provider: 'Facebook', enableCount: 'false', iconOnly:'true', iconImgUp:'images/facebook.jpg', iconImgOver:'images/facebookdown.jpg'},
    {provider: 'googleplus-share', enableCount: 'false', iconOnly:'true', iconImgUp: 'images/facebook.jpg'},
    {provider: 'Twitter', enableCount: 'true'},
    {provider: 'Share', enableCount: 'true'},
    {provider: 'Email'},
    {provider: 'Print'}],
    userAction: act,
    operationMode: 'multiSelect',
    grayedOutScreenOpacity: 20,
    onShareButtonClicked: function (eventObj) {
    }
});
```

Notice that I'm using the same image for facebook and google-plus for testing purposes, but this is what appears:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Optional parameters iconImgUp, iconImgOver, iconOnly and tooltip will not work with reserved name ("native") share buttons: ... 'googleplus-share' ...

[Source](http://developers.gigya.com/020_Client_API/010_Socialize/socialize.showShareBarUI)

Answer (score 0):

Since the GooglePlus share button is an iframe button hosted by Google, it can not be stylized.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me below

```js
var showShareBarUI_params = {
  containerID: 'componentDiv',
  shareButtons: [{ // General Share Button
    provider: 'share',
    tooltip: 'Share Button',
    iconImgUp: '/Images/icons_share.png'
  }, { // Facebook
    provider: 'facebook',
    tooltip: 'Recommend this on Facebook',
    iconImgUp: '/Images/icons_fb.png'
  }, { // Twitter
    provider: 'twitter',
    tooltip: 'Recommend this on Twitter',
    iconImgUp: '/Images/icons_twitter.png'
  }, { // Pinterest
    provider: 'pinterest',
    tooltip: 'Recommend this on Pinterest',
    iconImgUp: '/Images/icons_pin.png'
  }, { // Google+
    provider: 'googleplus',
    tooltip: 'Recommend this on Google',
    iconImgUp: '/Images/icons_gplus.png'
  }, ],
  showCounts: 'none',
  iconsOnly: 'true',
  moreDisabledProviders: 'Pinterest, hyves, delicious, digg, friendfeed, googlebookmarks, messenger, stumbleupon, skyrock, qq, sina, kaixin, renren, vznet, vkontakte, spiceworks, viadeo, nkpl, xing, tuenti, technorati, plaxo, reddit, formspring, tumblr, faves, newsvine, fark, mixx, bit.ly, hatena, misterwong, ask, amazon, gmail, baidu, box.net, whatsapp, netlog, evernote, aolmail, currenttv, yardbarker, blinklist, diigo, dropjack, segnalo, linkagogo, kaboodle, skimbit, facebook, twitter, googleplus, linkedin, mixi, odnoklassniki, douban',
  userAction: act,
  googleplusUserAction: gpAct,
  twitterUserAction: twAct
}
```